# 2006 Corvette Key Fob

Tags: chevrolet, keyless-entry

I am trying to associate a new key fob with a 2006 Corvette.  Accroding to the user's manual it reads:

> To match a new transmitter to your vehicle when you have a recognized
>   transmitter (two recognized transmitters are required for Canadian
>   owners), do the following:
>
> The vehicle must be off.   Have the recognized and new, unrecognized
>   transmitters on your person.   Go to the rear of the vehicle and
>   insert the vehicle key into the key cylinder located above the license
>   plate. See Hatch for more information on the key cylinder.   Open the
>   trunk.   Turn the key five times within five seconds.   The DIC will
>   display READY FOR FOB #X, where X can be 2, 3 or 4.   Place the new,
>   unrecognized transmitter in the glove box transmitter pocket with the
>   buttons facing towards the passenger's side.   Once the transmitter is
>   programmed, a beep will sound. The DIC will display READY FOR #X,
>   where X can be 3 or 4, or MAX # FOBS LEARNED.   Press the ACC button
>   (ignition switch).

My issue is that after turning the key five times within five seconds, my DIC (Driver Information Center) does not display the READY FOR FOB #X.... message at all.  Hoping someone reading this can help me out?

---

### UPDATE

I finally figured this out.  Things not mentioned in the manual that you need to do:

1. The car must be in Reverse if it's a manual transmission and it must be in Reverse while shutting it off.  I think the on board computer writes to internal flash memory during power mode going off and when it does, have the car in Reverse.
2. I had two dead key fobs.  One with a "1" and one with a "2" on the back side.  I made sure the one with the "2" was in the house.
3. Open the rear hatch with the key and leave it in the cylinder.
4. Open driver side door and leave it open.  I put the "1" fob into the glove box with the buttons facing the passenger side door.
5. Still with driver door open, I turned the key in the cylinder very rapidly and well within the 5 seconds.

Now here is the tricky part that doesn't seem documented anywhere...

1. You have to wait.  Wait roughly 30 seconds and my DIC finally gave the message ACCESSORY - OFF message.
2. I push the ACC button down (not up) and I get the message NO FOBS found.  This is also not mentioned in the manual or online anywhere.  My DIC would then go dark and I kept thinking it was not working but it just so happen I waited roughly a minute and the DIC lit back up and finally showed the AUTO LEARN in 10 minute message.
3. You then follow the directions in the manual as specified.
4. The last step in the manual says to push ACC when done.  I found after that step my FOBs that I programmed still did not work until I locked and unlocked the door with the buttons on the fob.
5. I had two fobs.  When I got the message FOB#1 was done and it asked for FOB#2, I took FOB#1 with me into the house and left it out of range when I came back with FOB#2.

I hope this helps someone else...

Comment: I was wondering if you ever found out the answer to your question, because I am having the same problem with my 2006?

Comment: @John: Sorry, no I have not.  Been meaning to get down to the dealer to see about this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good reference for the problem you seem to be having: [Program Spare Key FOB](http://forums.corvetteforum.com/c6-tech-performance/2074020-ok-im-lost-program-spare-key-fob.html)

> 1. The vehicle must be OFF.
> 2. Open the rear compartment.
> 3. Place a known key fob within the interior of the vehicle.
> 4. At the rear of the vehicle insert the vehicle key in the rear compartment lock cylinder located in the lower left and cycle the key 5 times within 5 seconds.
> 5. The DIC will display a message: READY FOR FOB X (X = fob 2, 3, or 4).
> 6. Place the replacement key fob in the glove box fob pocket with the buttons facing right.
> 7. A beep will occur and the DIC will display: READY FOR FOB X (X = fob 3 or 4) or MAX FOBS LEARNED.
> 8. If programming additional key fobs, repeat steps 5 and 6, or press the OFF/ACC portion of the ignition switch to exit programming mode.
> 9. Operate the active portion of each key fob to exit the programming and to verify correct system operation.

It looks like there is one main difference in the instructions; the known key fob needs to be in the interior of the vehicle while you cycle the key.  If having the known fob inside the vehicle does not work, try the steps recommended [here](http://forums.corvetteforum.com/1570351932-post19.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately none of those steps worked including the link you provided.  I had actually seen all that before posting here.  I came here as a last ditch effort after scouring the web for such info.

Answer (score -2):

Same problem thought my contacts were dirty. Tried by hand many times many speeds put my 07 in reverse and was able to get right into program mode.